# In-place destruction on type with overloaded operator->

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor, forwarding

Suppose some type `Foo` has an overloaded `operator->` that returns a `Bar*`:

```
struct Foo
{
    Bar* operator->();
};
```

If I want to destruct the returned `Bar` instance in-place from within the `Foo` class, can I write the following?

```
this->~Bar();
```

g++ does not like that code. It works if I write this:

```
(*this)->~Bar();
```

Does the "rescursive forwarding rule" not apply in this case? Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the rule for chaining `->`, found in 13.5.6 `[over.ref]` of the standard:

> An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3).

Since `this` is a pointer, not a class object, it doesn't apply.

Instead, this rule in 5.2.5 (`[expr.ref]`) is applicable:

> For the second option (arrow) the first expression shall have pointer to complete class type.  The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`; the remainder of 5.2.5 will address only the first option (dot).

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` is a pointer and *not* a reference and `->` for a pointer doesn't *have* a return value for forwarding to take place on. Consider equivalently

```
shared_ptr<std::string>* ptr = // some init
ptr->push_back('0'); // error
```

Comment: Of course `->` on a pointer has a return value.  (Well, 5.2.5 causes `this->~Bar()` to be replaced by `(*(this)).~Bar`, and 13.6 provides a return type for `(*(this))`.)  The recursion rule simply doesn't apply when `->` is used with a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a pointer to an object of type Foo.
You overwrote the operator -> for the object, not the pointer.

```
this->~Bar()
```

attempts to call the ~Bar() method in Foo.

```
(*this)->~Bar()
```

works because you call the -> operator of the object.

Comment: That's why Fred asked about chaining.